# Create new Visual Studio MySQL MVC Project; input string was not in the correct format

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

I tried to search how to solve my problem, but this issue happened to others after they have some code.

And I get this error immediately after clicking "Create new MySQL MVC Project" in MySQL tool tab, so I don't even have any code. I reinstalled MySQL, that didn't help, so, thinking that the error is too deep, simply did a factory reset on my PC, installed Visual Studio and MySQL, and that didn't help, either.

Here is the screenshot (I don't think that it can help you understand how to solve my problem, but what if I am wrong?):[image]

Comment: ... you have 10 rep now.

Comment: What Updates (i.e. Update 4), if any, have you installed? What version of the MySQL extensions did you install?

Comment: @TiesonT. Sorry, i can't understand which updates you talking about. Here are my MySQL extensions : http://img42.com/OMILr+

Comment: They are essentially service packs for Visual Studio. Update 4 is the latest: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44921

Comment: @TiesonT. Yeah, i have Update 4 : http://img42.com/5s5r0+

Comment: @TiesonT. Maybe i must try previous verion of MySQL?

Comment: Hard to say. I personally wouldn't bother with that project template, as it seems a bit out-of-date. Create a new MVC project, and then use NuGet to add the MySQL.Web and MySQL.Data.Entity packages.